# Маршрутизация до роутера из внешней сети через внутреннюю

Tags: linux, маршрутизация

Поскольку в роутер не попасть из интернета? хочу сделать маршрутизацию на двух ubuntu машинах.

Именование:
PC - мой десктоп
SRV - удалённый сервер 
M1 - удалённый роутер
INET - глобальная сеть интернет

Схема сети:
PC - INET - M1 - SRV

Предполагаемая схема маршрутизации:
PC - INET - M1 - SRV - M1 - SRV - INET - PC

Другими словами, нужно, чтобы M1 думал, что к нему обращается не PC, а SRV. Я пробовал изменить файлы hosts на обеих машинах, чтобы по домену m1.server я попадал на страницу M1. Но меня перебрасывает на ngnix страницу.

Comment: Почитайте про DNAT/SNAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение, это использовать VNC, [X forward](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine) или ssh/telnet:

```
root@PC: ssh root@SRV
root@SRV: ssh/telnet root@M1
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите внимательно на документацию к роутеру. Есть ряд моделей TP-Link, позволяющих получать доступ к WEB интерфейсу роутера по не стандартному порту из интернета.

Возможно стоит обратить внимание на средства удаленного администрирования TeamViewer, AmmyyAdmin и пр.

Чтобы работала вышеуказанная связка, стоит организовать виртуальную сеть (VPN) между PC и SRV, например с помощью LogMeIn Hamachi. А потом прописать route (см. `man route`) через интерфейс Hamachi.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть доступ к SRV и права root'а на нём, то один из вариантов это сделать на нём правила iptables перенаправляющие пакеты от PC на на M1, но уже промаркированные адресом SRV.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i $if_SRV_lan -d $ip_M1_lan -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $if_SRV_lan -j SNAT --to-source $ip_SRV_lan
iptables -A FORWARD -i $if_SRV_lan -o $if_SRV_lan -j ACCEPT
```

Примерно так, возможно потребуются небольшие доработки